# Как избежать ids дубликатов, когда события из разных внешних источников?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-database

Наше приложение будет получать события из разных внешних источников. Если пользователю нравится события то нажимает на “Like” button, затем, если это первый случай когда событие понравилось пользователю, то я должен сохранить это событие в Firebase database и поставить значение 1 в likes’ счетчик (который находится в event модели). Если это событие нравилось до этого другим пользователям, то значит я просто должен прибавить значение 1 в likes’ счетчик. Проблема состоит в том, что я не уверен в том, чтобы использовать оригинальное event id, так как из-за того, что мы получаем данные из разных источников, то может произойти проблема дубликатов ids, когда два абсолютно разных события будут иметь один и тот же id. Также я не могу использовать firebase ref key как id, так как одно и тоже событие если понравится разным пользователям то каждый пользователь не просто прибавит 1 к likes’s счетчик, а создает свою модель событий. Как лучше и с помощью чего решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, кроме event id используйте поле event from (id источника, откуда вы получаете события).

Во-вторых, создайте новую таблицу лайков с полями "event from", "event id", "user id", в которой вы будете учитывать лайки. Количество лайков вычисляйте при каждом изменении, исходя из данных этой таблицы и записывайте в поле "Количество лайков" таблицы "События".

Это немного усложнит логику приложения, зато позволит вам безошибочно учитывать лайки и отмену лайков при любом количестве пользователей и событий.